# I can't remember the word for the phrase don't -- me

Tags: word-usage

I can't remember the correct phrase you give someone if they are being overly nice to where it sounds condescending?

It would go like: don't --- me.

Would be a similar word to flatter or pander

Comment: don't patronize me?

Comment: Don't tase me bro?

Comment: @John You clearly move in more violent circles than me if tasing people counts as being overly nice!

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, what's sad is that's the first thing I thought of when I saw don't [blank] me... Even the second and third things weren't so nice! It may be time to get some Jesus...

Comment: @John Or a handful of restraining orders!

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet :)

Answer (score 3):

**Patronize** (patronise)
I remembered the word!

> 1. to behave towards (someone) in a way which is kind and friendly but which nevertheless shows that one thinks oneself to be more important, clever etc than that person.
>      *He's a nice fellow but he does patronise his assistants.*

([The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/patronise))

Comment: Could you accept this answer to show that is is the correct one? I have updated it to add the required detail necessary for an answer.